# webpack npm run build

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, npm

[image: Структура папок]

[image: Это webpack.config.js]

Когда пытаюсь сделать **npm run build**, должен появится файл **style.css**, когда настраивал **js**, то всё работало, как только начал добавлять **scss**, то перестал работать **npm run build**
Может кто знает

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52050643/8579902) советуют сделать так `npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin@next`

Также стоит обратить внимание, что если вы пользуетесь Webpack 4, то лучше использовать `mini-css-extract-plugin`, вместо `extract-text-webpack-plugin`.